# CSS Content Dısappearing on Zoom In

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers, position

https://github.com/KaanAlper/Discord-Card
On desktop browsers I can use it up to 125%, after that the content disappears.
In phone nothing is visible directly

I tried deleting the container and leaving the content directly, but even then the background gets bigger and smaller, apart from the buttons. Frankly, I'm just learning this language. Sorry in advance.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, however, when you zoom in on desktop it may inherit mobile styles. So, if you have content hidden on mobile, that may be the reason it gets hidden when you zoom beyond a certain point on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this block of code in your css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1470px) {
  .card-container {
    width: 1100px;
  }

  /* ↓↓↓ */
  .card:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `:last-child` pseudo-selector, but because you only have one `.card` element, it is both the first and the last child, so it gets hidden on screens smaller than 1470px. Browsers will apply mobile styles based on the zoom percent. If you want to know why, [this is a great answer](https://superuser.com/a/1004818).

Answer (score 0):

In the styles.css file you have:

```
/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 1470px) {
   .card-container {
    width: 1100px;
  }
   .card:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

By enlarging the page using zoom, the browser's viewport remains the same, but it begins to respond to break points in slightly different places, depending on how much you zoom in or out. This code:

```
.card:last-child {
 display: none;
}
```

makes it disappear unexpectedly because you accidentally trigger this breakpoint by zoom in.

Regards!